# Sprite kit crashes in iOS7.1 when runAction

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  //  self.SCREEN=[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MainScene" ofType:@"sks"];

    self.skScene = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];

    [self.skView presentScene:self.skScene];

    self.skScene.scaleMode=SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    self.face=(SKSpriteNode*)[self.skView.scene childNodeWithName:@"face_layer"];
    [self.face runAction:[SKAction rotateToAngle:30 duration:0]];
}
```

`face` is a `SKSpriteNode` inside of the scene,However this code always crashed in iOS7.1,works in 8.0 or 8.1.

```
0xd1b34c:  movl   $0x0, 0x28(%ecx)
0xd1b353:  cmpb   $0x0, 0xc(%ecx)
0xd1b357:  je     0xd1b364                  ; SKCAction::willStartWithTargetAtTime(SKCSprite*, double) + 46
0xd1b359:  movl   (%ecx), %eax
0xd1b35b:  movl   0x28(%eax), %eax      Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x36...)
0xd1b35e:  addl   $0x18, %esp
0xd1b361:  popl   %ebp
0xd1b362:  jmpl   *%eax
```

is it the bug of iOS7.1? Thanks

Comment: please edit your original question if you have new info, as far as I can tell this is exactly the same problem as before except that you posted a different code fragment. Please point out exactly what line the error occurs on.

Comment: Oh and check if you aren't simply using a method or class whose availability is mentioned as "iOS 8.0 and newer" in the class reference.